# How to load an image inside a div tag depending on a drop down selection

Tags: php, ajax, yii

I want to load an image inside a div tag according to a dropdown selection, I have used Yii's inbuilt AJAX capability to do this. Here's the code I have done so far,

Dropdown in the View :-

```
echo $form->dropDownList($model2,'name[0]', CHtml::listData(Stationery::model()-    >findAll('category_id = 54'), 'category_id', 'name'), array('empty'=>'--Please Select--'),
            array(
                 //'options'=>array($selected=>array('selected'=>'selected')),
                 'ajax'=>array(
                 'type'=>'POST',
                 'dataType'=>'json',
                 'url'=>CController::createUrl('order/echoeimage'),
                 //'imageUrl'=>Yii::app()->theme->baseUrl.'/images/storlocator_banner.png',
                 'data'=>array('position'=>'js: $(this).val()'),
                 //'update'=>'#img',
                 'success'=>'function(data) {
                     $("#img").html(data.total);
                 }',
                )));
<div id="img">

 </div>
```

Controller function :-

```
                  public function actionEchoeimage()
               {
                     /*Here goes your code to load the image*/
                       //$path = Yii::app()->theme->baseUrl."/images/storlocator_banner.png";
                      // echo CHtml::image($path); 

                       echo CJSON::encode(array(
                                'total'=>"value",
                                ));

               }
```

It didn't work as expected!So how to make it work?

Comment: If the aim is to have an image display, what you should do in jQuery is create an img tag and include a path to the image in the src attribute. At present what the code seems to be doing is setting the inner html of a tag with the id "img" which isn't the same. The path can be absolute (http://.../image.jpg) or relative (directory/image.jpg). Do make sure you understand the code you are manipulating.

Comment: depending on the number of images you can either do it client side or server side. so how many?

Comment: @bool.dev : only one image at a time. But images should be dynamically loaded according to database entries.

Comment: As @JamesPoulson mentioned, you're updating the html contents of your img tag, rather than the src attribute.  Your success function needs to have something more along the lines of : $("#img").attr('src', data.total), rather than the .html() call you're making.